# Is Quantum Fourier Transform defined for the standard basis only?

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform

I'm reading [the definition on Wikipedia for QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform#Definition) which is identical to the definition of my professor and they define:

$$|x\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} x_i |i\rangle $$

And then the QFT of $|x\rangle$ is:

$$F_N|x\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}y_i|i\rangle$$

And:

$$y_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n \exp\left(\frac{i 2\pi n k}{N}\right)$$

I don't understand: What are the $|i\rangle$ states? Could it be any arbitrary orthonormal basis? Or should it be the computational basis? I think I managed to build an example that  that demonstrates that basis matters:

Let's take N=4 and two bases:

$$\mathcal{B} = \{|\Phi_\pm\rangle, |\Psi_\pm\rangle\}, \mathcal{S}=\{|00\rangle,|01\rangle,|10\rangle,|11\rangle\}$$

Where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Bell basis. Let's try to transform $|\Phi_+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$:

**In basis $\mathcal{B}$**, $x_i = \delta_{0,i}$ ($\delta_{i,j}$ is kronecker's delta) hence:

$$y_k = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{3}x_n \exp\left(\frac{i \pi n \cdot k}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{3}\delta_{n,0} \exp\left(\frac{i \pi n \cdot k}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Which means that:

$$F_N|x\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left(|\Phi_+\rangle + |\Phi_-\rangle + |\Psi_+\rangle + |\Psi_-\rangle\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |00\rangle+ |01\rangle \right)$$

OTH, in [this Q&A](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15516/20792) one can see the computation result of $|\Phi_+\rangle$ computed with $\{|i\rangle\}$ being the standard basis $\mathcal{S}$, and write it as:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|00\rangle + \frac{1-i}{2}|01\rangle + \frac{1+i}{2}|10\rangle\right)$$

It's different then the result obtained in the computation here - $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |00\rangle+ |01\rangle \right)$) (translated to the standard basis).

Comment: Yes, the basis $\{|i\rangle\}$ can be any orthonormal basis. The QFT is a linear operator and the role of the basis is simply to obtain a *matrix* out of it - while the operator is defined more generally. The same linear operator can have different matrix "representations" depending on the choice of basis (e.g., standard basis vs a basis in which the operator is diagonal).

Comment: Now I notice that in both bases, the matrix representation of $F_4$ is the same. I'm still confused however - If the change of basis is a matter of a unitary matrix, I'd expect the matrix $F_N$ to be transformed as well..